# Exporting java application to .jar

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jar, eclipse-rcp

I need to export my java application for jar file, I use eclipse to build my application, but I have a problem: java application  calls some python scripts and  python scripts calls  some libraries such as "OPENCV" 
I need to use  this "jar" into my rcp application
Someone can help me how  can I do this ???
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should ask this in Java group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jython (ex JPython) instead of native Python.
But OpenCV is native code.
As far I can tell you can't pack it to a jar with no external dependencies.